# Convert fprintf result into a one column array matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I want to convert an
fprintf output into a single array column and store into A

Additional Note: the Pij is a sparse matrix

```
for m = 1:nl
    p = fb(m); q = tb(m);
fprintf('%8.3f\n', full(Pij(p,q)))
end
```

I'm trying the below code but it does not work. Appreciate your prompt solution as soon as possible . Thanks

```
A=sprintf('%8.3f\n', full(Pij(p,q)))
```

Comment: You may be looking for a cell array. Initialize A like `A = cell(nl, 1)` and then index it with `A{m} = sprintf(<stuff>)`

Comment: yes! I just want array of A  with only one column A=[1,2,3,4,5], Note that Pij=[1000;0023;0400...n] is a sparse matrix . That is why when I execute the fprintf it seemingly to produce a single array of but I need to store it in A after printing in command window

Comment: I've tried using this code but it doesn't work either producing []'s only.                       for m = 1:nl
p = fb(m); q = tb(m);
A = cell(nl, 1)
A{m} = sprintf('%8.3f\n', full(Pij(p,q)))
end

Comment: Don't initialize the array inside the loop